# What are the ideals of $End(R)$?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring (with unity if necessary) , then $End(R)$ i.e. the set of endomorphism of the ring  $R$ (the set of all ring homomorphisms from $R$ to $R$ ) forms a ring under point-wise function addition and function composition  . What are the ideals of this ring $End(R)$ ? If we replace $R$ by any commutative group $G$ , then also $End(G)$ is a ring under function addition and composition ; what then are the ideals of $End(G)$ ?

Comment: Normally $\operatorname{End}(R)$ denotes the set of homomorphisms of _rings_ $R\to R$. If you only consider the additive structure of$~R$, what is the point of starting with a ring in the first place (the multiplicative structure will be completely ignored)? In other words your second question is essentially the same as you first.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : your point is correct , I edited

Comment: Hm, at least if $R$ has unity, then $End(R)$ is not in general a ring as you describe. The additive inverse of the identity morphism would need to be the map $x\mapsto -x$, and that is only a ring homomorphism if the characteristics of $R$ is $2$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : So then to be a ring $End(R)$ on $(R,+)$ seems to be the correct choice ?

Comment: If you want $\text{End}(R)$ to be a ring then one way of doing it is to consider $\text{End}_R(R_R)$, i.e. the ring of $R$-module endomorphisms of the right $R$-module $R$.

Comment: @user73985: But the endomorphisms of $R$ as a right $R$-module are precisely left multiplications $x\mapsto ax$ by elements $a\in R$, which establishes an isomorphism $R\to \text{End}_R(R_R)$. So then the question would be asking for a description of the ideals in a completely general ring, which seems overly ambitious. Not that doing so for the endomorphism rings of general Abelian groups would be much less ambitious...

Comment: @SaunDev This question is too general.

Comment: @rschwieb : what is meant by "too general " :-) ?

Comment: @SaunDev I mean that it has no good answer because it is too broad. If you had a specific type of ring in mind, the question might become more answerable.